# Unable to remove light fixture because of a wire entry holder

Tags: electrical

[image]

Hello,

I'm trying to remove a florescent light fixture but a plastic yellow wire entry holder is preventing the fixture from coming off. (See photo) It looks like a holder that had been crimped with 3 wires in place. Note I'm referring to the yellow plastic holder on the fixture, not the yellow wire nuts.

How can I remove the holder? The wires are tight, so I can't pull the fixture away more than half an inch from the wall with the holder in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just squeeze together the two yellow tabs with small pliers and the strain relief should pop out. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I was able to squeeze the tabs and then use a screw driver to separate the tabs and pull the fixture off.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strain-relief clamped to the NM-B cable sheath. It's purpose it to prevent the cable from being pulled out of the fixture and putting strain on the wire connections.

Assuming that you are trashing the fixture, what I'd do is take a pair of pliers and try to break off one or both of the parts that are clamped on the cable (left and right side parts in your photo). One broken off, the cable should be free to come out.